# careers profile page silently stops adding answers after reaching 30

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I was adding answers to my profile when I noticed they were not being added anymore (without showing any error).

It seems there's a limit of 30 added answers, but when reaching that limit nothing happens (no warning is shown) and answers **seem to be added** but really **they're not** (to realize you have to double check that the answer was added to the list), so the user can foolishly continue adding answers to later find their answers are not there.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the report Nelson. This should be fixed now.